# Is there a way to create Numberic Textboxes using WPF xaml code?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpf-core-3.0

I am new to WPF. I need to create **textboxes which is only accept digits**. Not accepted any special characters, letters .

And the important thing is , **the code is only xaml not c#**.

I googled lot of websites , but i only get the code used c#. But i want in XAML code. Because i enclosed it like styles in controls.

Is there any way to do this? And if it is not possible Why?

Comment: No, it's not possible because XAML is a *markup* language.

Comment: How about this: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible because XAML is a *markup* language. It has no support for distinguishing between digits and other type of characters.

You should use a *programming* language such as C# to implement this kind of logic.